# @OneToMany prevent deletion if is part of set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql, cuba-platform

I am using Cuba Framework with Java JPQL

I have a relationship of:

> 1. Transaction_Sets
> 2. Transactions

Where

```
Transaction Entity
      @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSACTION_SET_ID")
        @OnDelete(DeletePolicy.DENY)
        protected Transaction_Set transaction_Set;
Transaction_Set entity  
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transaction_Set", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
        @OnDeleteInverse(DeletePolicy.DENY)
        protected List<Transaction> transactions;
```

I have tried many combinations of @ but for some reason it is not working.  All I want it to do is:

> 1. Stop the deletion of a transaction if it belongs to a Transaction_Set.
>      Whenever I try and delete the transaction it
>      deletes it and removes it from the transaction_set.
> 2. Delete all transactions of a transaction_set when the transacion_set is deleted.

Number (2) is working.  Number (1) I can't solve...

Have been pulling my hair out over this for the past day.

Am I going about this right?  I think it might be something to do with how the Cuba Framework is set up.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious setup would be the following:

```
// Transaction
@OnDelete(DeletePolicy.DENY)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANSACTION_SET_ID")
protected TransactionSet transactionSet;

// TransactionSet
@OnDelete(DeletePolicy.CASCADE) // won't work
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "transactionSet")
protected List<Transaction> transactions;
```

But it won't work because your requirements are contradictory: DENY policy on Transaction will prevent CASCADE deletion from the TransactionSet side. Probably the problem cannot be solved on the ORM level with `@OnDelete` and `@OnDeleteInverse` annotations, but you can implement one of the restrictions in an `AfterDeleteEntityListener` which is run when ORM has already done all its job.

So the mapping should be as follows (keep only the first restriction):

```
// Transaction
@OnDelete(DeletePolicy.DENY)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANSACTION_SET_ID")
protected TransactionSet transactionSet;

// TransactionSet
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "transactionSet")
protected List<Transaction> transactions;
```

And the entity listener (unfortunately you have to use plain SQL here):

```
package com.company.sample.listener;

import com.haulmont.bali.db.QueryRunner;
import com.haulmont.cuba.core.Persistence;
import com.haulmont.cuba.core.global.TimeSource;
import com.haulmont.cuba.core.global.UserSessionSource;
import com.haulmont.cuba.core.sys.persistence.DbTypeConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.haulmont.cuba.core.listener.AfterDeleteEntityListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.company.sample.entity.TransactionSet;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Component("sample_TransactionSetEntityListener")
public class TransactionSetEntityListener implements AfterDeleteEntityListener<TransactionSet> {

    @Inject
    private TimeSource timeSource;

    @Inject
    private UserSessionSource userSessionSource;

    @Inject
    private Persistence persistence;

    @Override
    public void onAfterDelete(TransactionSet entity, Connection connection) {
        QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
        DbTypeConverter dbTypeConverter = persistence.getDbTypeConverter();
        try {
            queryRunner.update(connection,
                    "update SAMPLE_TRANSACTION set DELETE_TS = ?, DELETED_BY = ? where TRANSACTION_SET_ID = ?",
                    new Object[]{
                            dbTypeConverter.getSqlObject(timeSource.currentTimestamp()),
                            userSessionSource.getUserSession().getCurrentOrSubstitutedUser().getLoginLowerCase(),
                            dbTypeConverter.getSqlObject(entity.getId())
                    });
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error deleting related transactions ", e);
        }
    }
}
```